# React App not communicating with express backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm having trouble getting by React app to work with the express backend in production. On my server I'm running `nginx` with a `conf` that looks like so:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;

  # react app & front-end files
  location / {
    root /var/www/my-site;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  # node api reverse proxy
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }
}
```

The contents of the react `build` folder are in `/var/www/my-site`. I enter my servers IP in the browser and it loads the index page without any issue. However when I hit the login button to call the login API I get the following error: `http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/api/onboard/login 404 (Not Found)`

In my React app I have `"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"` in `package.json` (which I understand to be useless in production but it works locally on my machine with the local express server) and my API endpoints looks something like this: `/api/onboard/login` (I'm using Fetch)

Now onto the express server, my `server.js` is like so:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000' }));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());


app.use(function(_, res, next) {
  res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

require('./app/routes/onboard-routes')(app);
//etc...
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on http://loclalhost:${PORT}`));
```

an example route:

```
app.post(
    '/api/onboard/login',
    [verifyLogin.checkLoginFields],
    controller.login
);
```

I am running the server using `NODE_ENV=production forever start server.js`

Just to clarify the server works on my local machine using `localhost` and with my React app using all the settings above. It just doesn't work on my remote production server.

Could anyone point me in the the right direction? Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: so in the error `http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/api/onboard/login` is the actual route to hit the backend server ?, if no then I guess you need to add the base url or ip of your server

Comment: Well xxx.xxx.xx.x is the same as my servers IP address. To load the website I’d enter http://xxx.xxx.xx.x into the browser. So isn’t the route in the error the correct one?

Comment: try the route with postman if it's working, and if it works then trying connecting local frontend with backend server not the local one

Comment: Just tried with postman. It doesn’t work with postman either. Same 404 error.

Comment: which means the server is not working on that end point need to debug that, why the server is not being hit there, better to look at node.js side